# Know what event triggered the after_commit of an ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following snippet:

```
class Product
 after_commit :do_something, on: %i(update create)

 def do_something
   if # update
     ...
   else # create
     ...
   end
 end
end
```

**How to know what event triggered the after commit here?**

Please don't tell me to have 2 after commits like:

```
after_commit :do_something_on_update, on: :update
after_commit :do_something_on_create, on: :create
```

Comment: Curious ... have you tried a `puts` (or something similar) inside the `do_something` callback that would dump out (i.e., `inspect`) the method's args (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_commit)? On the bottom of this Github Issues page for Rails (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/988) Rafeal Franca notes they're just arguments (might be worth a quick test).

Answer (score 12):

[ActiveRecord uses `transaction_include_any_action?`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d03d6fc33b4e9629e3e969c18bda4bdcd3c01c90/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb#L442):

```
def do_something
  if transaction_include_any_action?([:create])
    # handle create
  end
  if transaction_include_any_action?([:update])
    # handle update
  end
end
```

A transaction can include multiple actions. If both `:create` and `:update` are possible in the same transaction in your program you need two `if`s, not an `if`/`else`.

Answer (score 1):

How about just check the previous_changes of id, if it is `nil`, that means we are doing `create`

```
def do_something
   id_changes = self.previous_changes[:id]
   # Creating
   if id_changes && id_changes.first.nil?
     ...
   else # Updating
     ...
   end
 end
```